# Javascript Async Functions and Promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I have been reading about Promises and Async functions, and i come across a page where there is an example with code :

```
function doubleAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x * 2);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function addAsync(x) {
  const a = await doubleAfter2Seconds(10);
  const b = await doubleAfter2Seconds(20);
  const c = await doubleAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + a + b + c;
}

var toLog = addAsync(10);
console.log(toLog);
```

I used the JSFiddle and the Chrome console :
The "toLog" variable is a promise object with the promiseValue of 130.

Questions :

Inside the **doubleAfter2Seconds** function the sum is made inside the **"resolve"** function, if in the example we never pass the "resolve" function(through the then method in the promise object i think) how can we get the 130 result ?

Best regards
Thanks in advance

Comment: `130 = 10 + (10 * 2) + (20 * 2) + (30 * 2)` - do you know where 130 comes from now? hint: `x + a + b + c`

Answer (score 1):

> Inside the doubleAfter2Seconds function the sum is made inside the "resolve" function

No.

The multiplication is performed inside the anonymous (arrow) function that is passed as the argument to `Promise`.

The result of that expression is immediately passed as the argument to the `resolve` function.

The `resolve` function is created by the Promise constructor and passed as the first argument to the (previously mentioned) anonymous function.

(And then that value is returned to `a`, `b`, or `c` via the `await` keyword.)

Answer (score 1):

`then` doesn't directly connect to `resolve`. `resolve` is passed to the promise executor function (the function you pass to `new Promise`) to be used to resolve the promise. `then` just hooks up handlers for promise resolution, which critically are not directly linked to that `resolve` function, but to the general operation of promises.

The reason you don't see any callback function in the `addAsync` function is that it's an `async` function using `await`. `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar for promise generation and consumption. Roughly speaking, if we remove that syntactic sugar, `addAsync` looks like this:

```
function addAsync(x) {
  return doubleAfter2Seconds(10)
    .then(a =>
        doubleAfter2Seconds(20)
            .then(b =>
                doubleAfter2Seconds(30)
                    .then(c => x + a + b + c)
            )
    );
}
```

or perhaps more readably (or not):

```
function addAsync(x) {
  return doubleAfter2Seconds(10)
    .then(a => {
        return doubleAfter2Seconds(20)
            .then(b => {
                return doubleAfter2Seconds(30)
                    .then(c => {
                        return x + a + b + c;
                    });
            });
    });
}
```

As you can see, we call `doubleAfter2Seconds`, wait for its promise to resolve, and receive that resolution value as `a`, then do the same and get the resolution as `b`, then again with `c`, and finally do the `x + a + b + c` when we have all the parts. The function returns a promise (`then` creates a new promise, remember) which is resolved with that sum.

More on MDN:

- [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 0):

The function doubleAfter2Seconds is called 3 times, and everytime it awaits that the Promise get back before keep on running the rest of the code

So the first time it is called, after 2 seconds:

```
a = 10 * 2 = 20
```

The second time, after other 2 seconds:

```
b = 20 * 2 = 40
```

The third time, after other 2 seconds:

```
c = 30 * 2 = 60
```

The function is called by AddAsync, so x will be 10

The final result is computed as:

```
a + b + c + x = 20 + 40 + 60 + 10 = 130
```

In case you don't want to pass the resolve function and use then you need to nest the function doubleAfter2Seconds